# Mysql: ALTER TABLE and foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do

```
ALTER table tbl_name Engine=MyISAM;
```

and I get

```
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How can I perform above query without deleting table having foreign key?

Thank you in advance!

**UPD** have I understood correctly that only `MyIsam` supports fulltext search?

Comment: Why would you want to give up the protection that a foreign key gives you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER table tbl_name Engine=MyISAM;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

> The InnoDB storage engine supports checking of foreign key constraints. For storage engines **other than InnoDB**, MySQL Server parses the FOREIGN KEY syntax in CREATE TABLE statements, but does not use or store it.

[Foreign Key Differences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: You could at least give a hint, that MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys to be upvote worthy ;)

Answer (score 11):

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` does not help.

Foreign keys must be dropped manually if there are other InnoDB tables containing foreign key references towards the table you are converting to MyISAM. See also [this post on MySQL site](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12555).